# Make CSS Changes To Only Affect Mobile Browser

Tags: css, mobile

Trying to make some CSS changes, that will only affect view on mobile phones. I made changes below, but it also affects desktop views.

```
nav {
    margin-top: 140px;
}
```

&

```
ownmenu {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **media query** like

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    /* For mobile phones: */
    /* YOUR MOBILE STYLE HERE */
}
```

Hope it will help!